# Followers graph goes to -1 when there are no followers, and times get squished when showing hours

Tags: bug, area-51

When there are no followers on a proposal (e.g. [this one](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/85944/ballet)) the graph starts from -1:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Also, when you unfollow and re-follow a proposal with 0 followers, the time is messed up for a short while:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

To be honest, it probably shouldn't be possible to unfollow your own proposal (maybe this should be another discussion)?

Comment: It could be perhaps ok with the message "A mathematically impossible scenario has been produced and this proposal now has -1 follower, just to signify how poor it is."

Comment: That's [tag:status-bydesign]

Comment: @PythonMaster how come? What graph should go to -1 if it is measuring followers?

Comment: @PythonMaster believe me, Anna would have marked it as such if that was the case. Her edits and (now deleted) comments confirm it's a bug.